# using jQuery AJAX method in Laravel project . in the Create Page data didn't save

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

## this my create.blade.php page

**here the saveAudience function is not work**

when  We click the save Audience button , the data have to save or error message will appear , but after click the save Audience Button there are no any changes .

[text](http://localhost:8001/save-audience)

```
 
        function saveAudience() {
            var postData = {
                name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            
            };

            sendHttpRequest('{{ route("save-audience") }}','POST', postData, function (response){
                console.log(response);

                if (response.is_success) {
                    alert('Audience saved successfully');
                } else {
                    alert('Error: Audience not saved');
                }
            });
        }

        $('.btn-success').on('click', function() {
            saveAudience();
        });
```

**this my Controller Page**

```
  public function saveAudience(Request $request)
        {
            try {
                $validatedData = $request->validate([
                    'name' => 'required',
                    // Add validation rules for other fields here
                ]);

                // Start a database transaction
                DB::beginTransaction();

                // Perform the necessary database operations here
                $audience = new Audience();
                $audience->name = $validatedData['name'];
                // Assign other fields to the $audience model as needed
                $audience->save();

                // Commit the database transaction
                DB::commit();

                $response = [
                    'msg' => 'Audience saved successfully',
                    'status' => 'Success',
                    'is_success' => true,
                    'data' => [],
                ];
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                // Rollback the database transaction in case of an exception
                DB::rollback();

                $response = [
                    'msg' => 'Error: Audience not saved',
                    'status' => 'Failed',
                    'is_success' => false,
                    'dev_msg' => $ex->getMessage(),
                    'data' => [],
                ];
            }

            return $response;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNbZa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIXqe.png)`

Comment: Can you not do Audience::create(['name' => $validatedData['name'] ])  on the model directly, and not use the DB Facades. Also check the models Guarded or Fillable parameters

Comment: after i used this method : public function saveAudience(Request $request){
        try{
            $rules = array(
                'name' => 'required',
            );
            $customMessages = [
                'name.required' => 'Name cannot be empty',
            ];
   ...
.... this also not work.